# Apache - Redirect with ErrorDocument 403

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 403 /down.php
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

This just keeps feeding me the forbidden page without redirecting. I'm trying to deny all IPs except my own, and redirect everyone else to a maintenance page. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: So they are not seeing the `/down.php` page?

Comment: @JonLin correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx$
RewriteRule .* maintenance.php [L,R=302]
```

This will not throw a forbidden error, but will instead redirect them to a temporary (302) page.